# SQL and multiple statements in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm working on SQL server 2005 and I have a very simple stored procedure:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[tblTabel_Insert] 
@ID int,
@Code nvarchar(50) = null
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF  EXISTS (SELECT ID, code FROM tblTabel WHERE ID = @ID and code = @Code) 
    UPDATE tblTabel SET ID = @ID,code = @Code WHERE ID = @ID

ELSE
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tblTabel (ID,code) VALUES ( @ID ,@Code);
END
```

My question is: is it posible to have multiple queries in my stored procedure ?
I want to add the lines

```
UPDATE tblTabelB SET ID = @ID,code = @Code WHERE ID = @ID
UPDATE tblTabelC SET ID = @ID,code = @Code WHERE ID = @ID
```

in my if exists section. How do I change my stored procedure in the correct way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put them between BEGIN and END

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT ID, code FROM tblTabel WHERE ID = @ID and code = @Code) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblTabel SET ID = @ID,code = @Code WHERE ID = @ID
    UPDATE tblTabelB SET ID = @ID,code = @Code WHERE ID = @ID
    UPDATE tblTabelC SET ID = @ID,code = @Code WHERE ID = @ID    
END   
ELSE
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tblTabel (ID,code) VALUES ( @ID ,@Code);
END
```

Answer (score 17):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT ID, code FROM tblTabel WHERE ID = @ID and code = @Code) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblTabel SET ID = @ID,code = @Code WHERE ID = @ID
    UPDATE tblTabelB SET ID = @ID,code = @Code WHERE ID = @ID
    UPDATE tblTabelC SET ID = @ID,code = @Code WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

Comment: @Sjemmie:  That's the point of having a stored procedure.  You can use conditionals, make calculations, have multiple inserts, deletes, updates, whatever you want.  :)