# Update two different tables using stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-update, dataset

What I'm trying to achieve is to modify some columns in two different tables only using one stored procedure

```
SELECT 
    ccpa.idActividad,
    ccpa.sTitulo,
    ccpa.dFechaInicioEstimada,
    ccpa.dFechaInicioReal,
    ccpa.dFechaEstimada,
    ccpa.dFechaResolucion,
    ccpa.iProgreso
FROM 
    dbo.Ctrl_ClienteProyectosActividades ccpa;

SELECT 
    ccph.idHito,
    ccph.sHito,
    ccph.dFechaInicioEstimada,
    ccph.dFechaInicio,
    ccph.dFechaCierreEstimada,
    ccph.dFechaCierreReal,
    ccph.iProgreso
FROM 
    dbo.Ctrl_ClienteProyectosHitos ccph;
```

Those are the columns I want to improve.

So far I have this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGantt_editar] 
    @sTitulo VARCHAR(50),
    @dFechaInicioEstimada DATETIME,
    @dFechaInicioReal DATETIME,
    @dFechaEstimada DATETIME,
    @dFechaResolucion DATETIME,
    @iProgreso INT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Editar 
    SET dFechaEstimada = ISNULL(@dFechaEstimada, dFechaEstimada),
        @dFechaInicioReal = ISNULL(@dFechaInicioReal, dFechaInicioReal),
        ....
    WHERE 
        Editar = @dFechaI

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
```

Any idea of how could I achieve this? any suggestion would be highly appreciated Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL and multiple statements in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432612/sql-and-multiple-statements-in-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing separate update commands but in single Stored Procedure (i.e. the way you want).

So instead of this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGantt_editar] 
@sTitulo VARCHAR(50),
@dFechaInicioEstimada DATETIME,
@dFechaInicioReal DATETIME,
@dFechaEstimada DATETIME,
@dFechaResolucion DATETIME,
@iProgreso INT
AS 
BEGIN
UPDATE Editar 
SET dFechaEstimada = ISNULL(@dFechaEstimada, dFechaEstimada),
    @dFechaInicioReal = ISNULL(@dFechaInicioReal, dFechaInicioReal),
    ....
WHERE 
    Editar = @dFechaI

SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
```

You can write this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGantt_editar] 
@sTitulo VARCHAR(50),
@dFechaInicioEstimada DATETIME,
@dFechaInicioReal DATETIME,
@dFechaEstimada DATETIME,
@dFechaResolucion DATETIME,
@iProgreso INT
AS
 BEGIN
UPDATE Editar 
SET dFechaEstimada = ISNULL(@dFechaEstimada, dFechaEstimada) where Editar =@dFechaI

UPDATE Editar 
SET @dFechaInicioReal = ISNULL(@dFechaInicioReal, dFechaInicioReal) WHERE Editar = @dFechaI

SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
```

Hope this helps.